# how to run and debug bash script from VSCode

Tags: bash, visual-studio-code

How do I run and debug bash script from VSCode. I have this setup in my Ubuntu machine. Is there any way to configure so that when I say run it execute the bash script?

I did install the bash debug extension but I get this error

> rogalmic.bash-debug-0.3.7/bashdb_dir/command/source.sh: line 41:
>   /dev/stdin: No such device or address

Comment: "You can create multiple terminals open to different locations and easily navigate between them. Terminal instances can be added by clicking the plus icon on the top-right of the TERMINAL panel or by triggering the Ctrl+Shift+` command. This action creates another entry in the drop-down list that can be used to switch between them." [Source](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/integrated-terminal)

Answer (score 5):

You are getting that error because you need to attach a terminal to the script's input/output.

The bash debug extension works for me.

Try a debug launch configuration like this:

```
"configurations": [
  {
    "type": "bashdb",
    "request": "launch",
    "name": "Bash simple",
    "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}",
    "program": "${file}",
    "terminalKind": "integrated"   <---- This attaches the integrated terminal.
  }
]
```

Then open the script file in Code and press F5.

Comment: where do you put this exactly?

Comment: @Max VSCode: Where? ... in a launch.json file or the launch section of a code-workspace file.

Answer (score 1):

[image: Bash Code]

From the run option in your integrated terminal, change the option to be the shell type you want to run your code in.

> You can create multiple terminals open to different locations and
> easily navigate between them. Terminal instances can be added by
> clicking the plus icon on the top-right of the TERMINAL panel or by
> triggering the Ctrl+Shift+` command. This action creates another entry
> in the drop-down list that can be used to switch between them.

More information on the integrated terminals [here](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/integrated-terminal).

Comment: but then how would I debug? The teminal will only allow me to execute the commands

Comment: @kumar Sorry, perhaps with the debug install you can contact the developer as per his [repo](https://github.com/rogalmic/vscode-bash-debug)? Slight misinterpretation of the question on my behalf. Can you also check you've got [dependencies](https://github.com/rogalmic/vscode-bash-debug) as required?

Comment: Just installed the extension via Visual Code's marketplace and had no issues, and was functional. Perhaps reinstall Code and redownload the extension. I'd be curious as what the contents of `source.sh` was.